# Will invoking Apex code in a flow help the flow stay under the CPU limit and other flow limits?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am about to design a flow but I suspect that it will exceed flow limits since the flow loops through 200 or so records and needs to create records on other objects based on them. Would I achieve any benefit by having the flow find the records and then passing the ~200 records to invokable Apex code to process them and then have the flow continue to update a parent account? Or will Salesforce look at the whole process as the flow running and if it hits ~10 seconds CPU time it'll stop and throw an error or hit another flow limit and show another error?

Answer (score 2):

Flows run slower than Apex (not much, maybe 20% or so in most cases). Your main concern should be the 2,000 executed elements limit. This gives you only a maximum of 10 elements per record at 200 records, so any loop larger than 10 should definitely be written in Apex. CPU time, however, is a global time limit, including both Flow and Apex execution time (but not database or callout time).